# Resizing ubuntu partition after uninstalling windows using GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[The screenshot from GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc2rB.png) showing the structure of my partitions.

The unallocated space is the one where windows was previously installed. Now I want to add that partition to sdb3. When I click resize option, I cannot add it to ext4 /home.

What I have tried so far: 
I have watched some of the youtube videos and they address the issue where unallocated space is inside the partition already. In my case, unallocated space is outside the partition.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: One solution: Backup your data and clean-install. Wipe all the unnecessary partitions away at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using a MBR partition table, and using extended partitions, resizing can be a little bit tricky, but here we go...

**Note**: If you have good backups, you may just wish to wipe the disk and reinstall Ubuntu fresh

**Note**: You don't want to add space to sdb3, but rather sdb6 and sdb7.

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- remember your **swapoff** command for /dev/sdb5
- right-click on /dev/sdb3 in the lower pane and select **move**
- **move** /dev/sdb3 partition all the way left

  - if this gives you trouble, stop here, let me know, and we'll do it another way
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sdb3 all the way right
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sdb7 right to add ~70G to /home
- **move** /dev/sdb7 partition all the way right
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sdb6 all the way right, adding ~15G to /
- click the Apply icon

Comment: Thanks I just wiped the disk and reinstalled ubuntu fresh